# opacity of overlapping partially transparent elements

Tags: html, css, math, transparency

if you have one `<div>` element with an opacity of .5 and another `<div>` element overlaying the first with an equal opacity then what is the opacity of the two put together?

It's not,

- .5 × .5

nor is it,

- .5 + .5

How do I calculate such a problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I believe the formula you are looking for would be 1-(x × y)