# Opacity and the overlay: the algorithm

Tags: css, algorithm, html, opacity

I have to create a system that work with some div and their opacity.

I'm going directly to some examples; all the divs are black:
- I have 2 divs and they overlap. The divs have opacity X and X, so the overlap area will result with opacity 1.

- I have 10 divs, and they overlap. The divs have opacity x1, x2, ... , x10 and the overlap area of all the divs will result with opacity 1. The overlap area of 9 (of 10) divs will result more transparent than the overlap area of 10 divs, and so on...

How to accomplish this? I need an algorithm that gives me the "X" opacity param of each div.

Thanks all.

SOLVED!

final opacity = 1-(1-op1)(1-op2) or op1+op2-op1*op2

log 0.01 = x*log op

where op is the opacity of the single level

(thanks to a genius friend)

Comment: If you've solved this, could you add the solution as an answer (and then accept it)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution:

final opacity = 1-(1-op1)(1-op2) or op1+op2-op1*op2

log 0.01 = x*log op

where op is the opacity of the single level

Comment: I do not understand this equation.  Could you explain the `or` statement, and the log equation below it?

Answer (score 0):

Found your problem interesting. I am no mathematician or some physics expert so just a guess.

Can we say that overlap of two divs will result into an overlap area whose opacity is addition of two divs opacity. So if

```
D1's opacity = 0.1 
and 
D2's opacity = 0.2 
their overlap opacity = 0.3. (can it be?)
```

So if 4 more divs overlap on them if addition reaches more than 1 it will mean that combined overlap area will be completely black.

Alternatively, might I suggest you to put your problem on programer.stackexchage.com too, people there simply love algorigthms :)

Ok, maybe it doesn't work that way. I created a simple jsFiddle. Someone here already has, anyways I will give you this link. http://jsfiddle.net/gHjrN/

Here I created four divs with varied opacity. Their opacity totals reached way above 1.0 but still their collective overlap is not yet jet black. Btw, why are you searching for an algorithm, browsers seem to do it themselves :D

Ok, I found some link you might find helpful [opacity of overlapping partially transparent elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5711624/opacity-of-overlapping-partially-transparent-elements). Opacity calculated may be `1-(D1's opacity X D2's opacity)`

Comment: Oh yeah, i did a jsFiddle to: http://jsfiddle.net/XcUVL/
I think it's that 1-(D1's opacity X D2's opacity)... I will do an inverse algorithm and i will post id :)

Thanks so much!

Comment: NO!!! there is a problem!
1-(0,5*0,5) = 0,75
but 1-(0,75*0,75) = 0,46.... less opacity with two levels with more opacity?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I completely understand the question, but if I were you I'd set up a jsFiddle to test this.

Something along the lines of this would be a good starting point for some prototypeing:

CSS:

```
#contain {position:relative;}
#actual-black {background-color:black}

.overlap {
    position:absolute;top:1em;left:0;
    background-color:black; opacity:0.2;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="contain">
<div id="actual-black">The background is opaque black</div>
<div class="overlap">This is transparent black</div>
<div class="overlap">This is transparent black</div>
<div class="overlap">This is transparent black</div>
<div class="overlap">This is transparent black</div>
</div>​
```

Play around with the different number of transparent divs, and the opacity on them.  Set up a new class (eg "overlap2") and apply different opacities to it, etc...

I'll be surprised if there's an "algorithm" to handle this that works across all browsers, but am really interested in the results (and hope I'm wrong and that this is actually predictable) so please do post what you find.